# How is Activity leak detected at run-time in Android?

Tags: android, android-activity, memory-leaks

From time to time, I can see logcat messages reporting activity leak. For example:

```
Activity com.android.internal.app.ChooserActivity has leaked IntentReceiver com.android.internal.app.ResolverActivity$1@4144d6e8 that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?

android.app.IntentReceiverLeaked: Activity com.android.internal.app.ChooserActivity has leaked IntentReceiver com.android.internal.app.ResolverActivity$1@4144d6e8 that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?
     at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:763)
     at android.app.LoadedApk.getReceiverDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:567)
     at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiverInternal(ContextImpl.java:1081)
     at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiver(ContextImpl.java:1068)
     at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiver(ContextImpl.java:1062)
     at android.content.ContextWrapper.registerReceiver(ContextWrapper.java:341)
     at com.android.internal.content.PackageMonitor.register(PackageMonitor.java:65)
     at com.android.internal.app.ResolverActivity.onCreate(ResolverActivity.java:99)
     at com.android.internal.app.ChooserActivity.onCreate(ChooserActivity.java:53)
     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2033)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2104)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:132)
     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1157)
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4575)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556)
     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

My question is: how is this activity leak detected?

Comment: An `Activity` and a `Service` can communicate with each other. But only when the `Activity` registers to that particular `Service` first. When the `Activity` closes and gets destroyed. The `Activity` has to unregister from the `Service`. Typically, you do this in the OnDestroy-method. If you don't unregister from the `Service` and your `Activity` is destroyed, you will get a leak.

Answer (score 1):

To detect memory leak in code, you need to install [Memory Analyzer Tool](http://www.eclipse.org/mat/downloads.php) plugin for eclipse.

To understand how to use MAT, please see the following link: http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2011/03/memory-analysis-for-android.html

This is a very useful plugin, though a bit difficult to understand at first go but as you will use it, you will detect the memory leak in no time.

If you face any difficulty, please ask me anytime.

Thank you :)

Comment: First of all, this is different from typical memory leaks, where memory usage keeps increasing. Second, MAT is used to analyze a heap snapshot, while what I'm asking is run-time/realtime detection of activity leak.